# What is the difference between matrix and array?

Tags: matlab, math

What is the more generalized term? 
Why is MATLAB named matrix laboratory, then?

Comment: Isn't a matrix multidimensional. As in it's a 2D array?

Comment: In computing, when I hear "array", I think of a generic [data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure).  And to me, a [matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29) is a particular kind of array the obeys certain rules of addition, multiplication, transformation, etc.  In  MATLAB, as opposed to Javascript or PHP, I tend to use them synonymously.

Comment: I think, array is more generalized. Often matrix is defined as 2D array. 1D arrays are often called vectors, and arrays with more then two dimensions - tensors

Comment: http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html

Answer (score 10):

A matrix is a practical way to represent a linear transformation from a space of dimension *n* to a space of dimension *m* in the form of a *nxm* array of scalar values.

It is also very practical to perform linear algebra operation in a very systematic way that can be implemented on a computer. For instance if matrix *A* represents the linear transformation *f* and matrix *B* the linear transformation *g*, then the composition *f* o *g* writes as A*B where `*` denotes matrix multiplication. Matlab has also a lot of routines related to **matrix operations** (i.e. linear algebra operations) like `det`, `pinv`, `svd` etc...

As you can still see nowadays in Matlab, operators like `*`, `/` are strongly tied to matrix operations and thus strongly tied to linear algebra operations, which I think was the original goal of matlab in its early elaboration, hence its name (surely quite speculative but guess not so far from reality).

To perform element-wise operations on n-dimensional data sets, you have to write `.*`, or `./`. denoting you are now performing **array operations**.

I would not say **array operations** encompass **matrix operations**, they are different. The later ones relate to linear algebra, while the other ones just relate to a practical way to operate on large sets of data. These data are not limited to be numbers, they are just n-dimensional data sets of whatever (string, numbers, cells, etc...).

Matlab also has a very synthetic syntax to perform **array operations** on sub-blocks (i.e. linear/logical subscripts) that makes it very easy to reorganize data sets in just one line of code before applying subsequent *matrix* or *array* operations.

Comment: I think this is well put and insightful.  MATLAB gets its name, **mat**rix **lab**oratory, because it "...is optimized for operations involving matrices and vectors." http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking about MATLAB, the word "matrix" typically refers to a 2d array, whereas an "array" can be n-dimensional.

Early versions of MATLAB supported only 2d matrices, not n-dimensional arrays. I believe support for n-dimensional arrays was introduced in version 5 of MATLAB.

Comment: I began with Matlab at version 4 and I'm also pretty sure it didn't have n-dimensional arrays

Answer (score 0):

I would say that MATLABs matrix is a more advanced kind of array if you compare to the c-style arrays, eg `double array[]`, or the Java array, eg `double arry2[]`. I would also say that the matlab matrix is better for mathematical purposed than the c++ vector or Java ArrayList. However, if you mean the matlab array I would say that it is more complicated. I would then recommend the link about [matlab data](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-data.html) which describes the `mxArray` type, used to store most of the data in matlab. The question is hard to answer completely without better description of what you mean with array, but I would say that regarding the type there is no difference between an array like `a = [1,2,3,4]` and matrix like `b = [1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8]`. There can also be matrices of higher dimensions as `c = ones(3,4,3)`. These are in general called matrices as well in MATLAB, or if you need to be more specific N dimensional matrices.